# Can I send XLS/XLSX files using Express res.sendFile()?

Tags: express, xlsx, sendfile

I've posted too many questions about this but I keep hitting a wall so I keep asking. Can you send an XLS or XLSX file using Express' `res.sendFile()`?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
res.sendFile(
    path.join(__dirname, '../testing/'),
    `${fileName}`,
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
    }
  );
```

Even though `fileName` has the value of `filename.xlsx`, it never uses the XLSX file; it always defaults to `index.html`. I always get the following error:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/username/Documents/app/testing/index.html']
```

Answer (score 0):

`sendFile` neither knows nor cares that you're trying to send an XLS/XLSX file. It only knows that you're trying to send a file.

So, yes, you can, but you have to call `sendFile` properly.

**You've put the filename as a separate argument (which [will be parsed as the `options` argument](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile)), instead of putting it in the `path` argument.**

```
res.sendFile(
    path.join(__dirname, '..', 'testing', fileName),
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
    }
  );
```

Notice that I took the liberty of removing the apparently redundant expression template literal stuff. I've also split `'../testing/'` up for you: you're supposed to put discrete components into `path.join` as much as possible, for clarity.